# Nodemon alias requiring modules like webpack

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, nodemon

Webpack offers a pretty powerful tool to alias requiring modules but since I moved to an isomorphic stack, my express is now loading some of the webpack related world and my aliasing is breaking (erroring the server).

Is there a way, preferably via gulp, to alias my folder structure?

I'd love this:
`import ApplicationStore from './client/scripts/stores/ApplicationStore';`
to just be
`import ApplicationStore from 'stores/ApplicationStore';`

Answer (score 1):

You can add directories to the module search path with the [resolve.root](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-root) option.

```
resolve: {
  root: [`${__dirname}/client/scripts`],
}
```